# Ethers 6 transaction receipt events information

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, events, testing

How i can get event name and params from tx receipt with Ethers 6?
I wanna write test to check if event was emitted.

Before each

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
    amount = tokens(10)

    const connectedToken = Token.connect(deployer)

    tx = await connectedToken.transfer(receiver.address, amount)
    result = await tx.wait()
})
```

Test

```js
it("Emits a Transfer event", async () => {
            //console.log(result.logs)
            const event = result.events[0]
            assert.equal(event.event, "Transfer")
            const args = event.args

            assert.equal(args._from, deployer.address)
            assert.equal(args._to, receiver.address)
            assert.equal(args._value, amount)
        })
```

And my solidity code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Token {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint256 _totalSupply
    ) {
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        totalSupply = _totalSupply * (10 ** decimals);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }

    //function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256) {}
    function transfer(
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    ) public returns (bool success) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question seems to have the answer, is it that the test is failing? if so explain what its throwing and whats inside `result` if you print it

Comment: @JulissaDC ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'events')```

Comment: try to `await result` before calling `const event = result.events[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem with v6 of ethers.  In v5, the events were part of the transaction receipt, but not in v6.

In looking at the "Getting Started" section of the docs for ethers v6, I found a section on events.  You have to set up a filter for the specific event, and then query it to get the events for the past n blocks.  then your tests can use the 'args' for testing.  Here is some code I just got working:

```
        it('emits Transfer event', async () => {
            filter = token.filters.Transfer
            events = await token.queryFilter(filter, -1)
            const event = events[0]

            expect(event.fragment.name).to.equal('Transfer')

            const args = event.args
            expect(args.from).to.equal(deployer.address)
            expect(args.to).to.equal(receiver.address)
            expect(args.value).to.equal(amount)
        })
```

It also works with other events as expected, ie:  `filter = token.filters.Approval`

I am using hardhat-toolbox 3.x, and the Chai assertions.
Happy testing!

Answer (score 8):

Transaction Receipt events in ethers.js v6 available at .logs getter. You could miss it because you can't see it while logging whole transaction receipt object, but you can see it by calling "logs" property directly.

For example using your code:

```
tx = await connectedToken.transfer(receiver.address, amount)
result = await tx.wait()
console.log('transaction events', result.logs);
```

[Here's](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/bcc4d8c8701cfe980742b7d33dc7b0ee4fc48fec/src.ts/contract/wrappers.ts#L60) source code of ContractTransactionReceipt class.

Comment: Thank you! It's so misleading, especially because it is nowhere in the migration v5 to v6 doc

Comment: can't understand how i can get the first argument of the event, i tried 
```let logs = result.logs[0].args.id``` but there is a strange value