# logging events while testing

Tags: solidity, blockchain, events, mocha, chai

In Current Version of ethers v6 ., once the event is emitted how we should log them ., because the older method of logging from transaction receipt is not working "
for example this is my function code

```
function getWinner(uint256 id) public{
        bool istimepassed = isTimePassed(id);
        if(!istimepassed){
            revert Voting_stillopen();
           
        }
        else{
            string memory winner;
            uint256 max=0;
            uint256 len=pollidtovote[id].options.length;
            for(uint256 i=0;i<len;i++){
                string memory name=pollidtovote[id].options[i];
                uint256 count=votecount[id][name];
                if(count>max){
                    max=count;
                    winner = name;
                }
            }
            emit winnerAttained(id,winner);
            console.log(winner);
            pollidtowinner[id]=winner;
            // uint256 len=voterslist[id].length;
            // for(int i=0;i<len;i++){

            // }
        }
```

for this i have wrote a specific test for the event of winner attained (Note : I have declared the winner as an indexed string )

```
it.only("Calculates the winner from an emitted event", async function () {
      const { VotingSystem, id, options } = await loadFixture(EnterVote);

      await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        VotingSystem.once("winnerAttained", async () => {
          try {
            // assert(endingtimestamp > startingtimestamp);

            resolve();
          } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
          }
        });
        const txnresponse = await VotingSystem.getWinner(id);
        const txnreceipt = await txnresponse.wait(1);
        console.log(txnreceipt.logs[0].args.target);
      });
```

I have tried all the ways to log the winner but In the present version of ethers it is not working ., So if anyone knows please help

Comment: Might be the same question
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152626/ethers-6-transaction-receipt-events-information